# Getting the items in listview in android

Tags: android

I am developing an application where, each row in the list view has got five text views(t1..t5) and values in it. I have twenty rows with each row having different values in the textviews.Now, when i click on an item(on a single row) an another page opens up with five text views. My questions is, how to get the values of the text views in each row to the page i am navigating into and put the values in the textviews. The values should also vary accordingly depending upon the position i am clicking on.

Could you please help me in this concept.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {


       String str = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.someid)).getText().toString();

       //Now pass this to intent
       Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                SomeActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("string", str);
        startActivity(intent);

    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use onItemClickListener

```
contests_listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
//Here you can write code
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the items from the `ListView` and send them in `Intent`

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                TextView txt1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt1);
                TextView txt2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2);
                TextView txt3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt3);
                TextView txt4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt4);
                TextView txt5 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt5);

                String strTxt1 = txt1.getText().toString();
                String strTxt2 = txt2.getText().toString();
                String strTxt3 = txt3.getText().toString();
                String strTxt4 = txt4.getText().toString();
                String strTxt5 = txt5.getText().toString();

            }
        });
```

add strTxt1, strTxt2, strTxt3, strTxt4 and strTxt5 to `Intent`

Answer (score 0):

Inside the onCreate() method of your MainActivity, do the following

```
ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
    int position, long id) {


   String str1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt1)).getText().toString();
String str2 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt2)).getText().toString();
String str3 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt3)).getText().toString();
String str4 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt4)).getText().toString();
String str5 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt5)).getText().toString();

   //Start a new intent and pass all these string values to your new Activity
   Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            NewActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("t1", str1);
    intent.putExtra("t2", str2);
    intent.putExtra("t3", str3);
    intent.putExtra("t4", str4);
    intent.putExtra("t5", str5);
    startActivity(intent);

}
});
```

Now, inside the onCreate() method of your new activity do this

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String str1 = intent.getStringExtra("t1");
String str2 = intent.getStringExtra("t2");
String str3 = intent.getStringExtra("t3");
String str4 = intent.getStringExtra("t4");
String str5 = intent.getStringExtra("t5");

TextView t1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
t1.setText(str1);
.....
```